# In meta-analysis, how can we use l'abbe plots to gauge what effect size we should use?

Tags: meta-analysis

Typically, in meta-analysis measures like Risk Ratios, Odds Ratios, and even Risk Differences are used to compute effect measures. I am wondering how a l'abbe plot can guide us towards which one to use. Are there certain features in a l'abbe plot that might give us more intuition to which of the three work better?

For example, in the package `metabin`, there is a function called `labbe`. In the documentary, it says:

> Furthermore, this plot can aid to choose a summary measure (odds
>   ratio, risk ratio, risk difference) that will result in more
>   consistent results.

My question is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the risk difference is likely to be appropriate then the differences should be similar across the range of $x$ and $y$ values plotted. So we would expect to see them about a line $y = x + c$ for some value of $c$, a constant. This is easiest to see if you plot on the scale of raw proportions. If the ratio between the proportions is likely to be informative then they would lie about a line of the form $y = c x$. It is easiest to examine the former sometimes by plotting on the log scale when it becomes $\log(y) = \log(x) + c$. If you do the same on the logit scale the line would correspond to constant odds ratios.